# How to get the ID of a custom attribute when having the custom attribute text value?

Tags: attributes, eav

I want to update a custom attribute and I can do that like this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->loadByAttribute('sku',"mysku");

$product->addAttributeUpdate('manufacturer', 281);
echo $product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
```

In `addAttributeUpdate()` instead of passing `281` which is the ID 
I only have an attribute text so I should get the ID of that attribute text and insert it in the place of `281`

How can I do that?

```
$attrtext = 'myatttext';
$product->addAttributeUpdate('manufacturer', $attrtext->getId() /* ???????? */);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order for you to achieve what you're looking for, implement the following code:

```
// attribute code
$attribute_code = 'manufacturer';

$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); 

// load attribute by attribute code
$attribute = $productModel->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_code);

// load product by sku 
$product = $productModel->loadByAttribute('sku', 'mysku');

// Validate attribute
if ($attribute->usesSource()) { 
    // load option Id by value text
    $attribute_value_id = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionId('myatttext'); 

    // update product attribute
    $product->addAttributeUpdate($attribute_code, $attribute_value_id);

    echo $product->getAttributeText($attribute_code);
}
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: you are just awesome

Comment: @NeginNickparsa you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('custom_attribute_code');
if ($attribute)
{
    echo $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
}
```